# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: homeViewController1

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, armv7

Hi I'm facing the  "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" problem.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_voiceLoad", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setVoiceName:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelGetSpeakingRate", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 speakModelTalker:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelCloseInputTextQueue", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 speakModelTalker:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelPollPhraseQueueBlocking", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 speakModelTalker:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelSetVoice", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setVoiceName:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_phraseGetSampleCount", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 speakModelTalker:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_phraseGetSamples", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 speakModelTalker:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelFlush", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 stopSpeak1] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelOpen", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setUpModelTalkerVoice:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelSetPlaying", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setUpModelTalkerVoice:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelWriteRegistry", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setVoiceName:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelUsePhraseQueue", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setUpModelTalkerVoice:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelSetInputText", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 speakModelTalker:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelLoadRegistry", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setUpModelTalkerVoice:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelSetSpeakingRate", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setUpModelTalkerVoice:] in HomeViewController1.o
  -[HomeViewController1 speakModelTalker:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelGetVoice", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setUpModelTalkerVoice:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_phraseMarkForDeletion", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 speakModelTalker:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelStart", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 actionDidSpeakOrPublish:] in HomeViewController1.o
  -[HomeViewController1 textTapped:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelStop", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 stopSpeak1] in HomeViewController1.o
  -[HomeViewController1 actionDidSpeakOrPublish:] in HomeViewController1.o
  -[HomeViewController1 setVoiceName:] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelListVoices", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 voices] in HomeViewController1.o
"_channelSetPitch", referenced from:
  -[HomeViewController1 setUpModelTalkerVoice:] in HomeViewController1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I done this below steps.

1. Clean the project.
2. Deleted derived data and trash files.
3. Quit the Xcode and reopened.
4. Build Active Architecture Only set to 'NO'.

but still i'm facing the this linker error. Has anyone worked with this program and can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HomeViewController1.o

This .o shows two things

> 1. File HomeViewController1 is added two time, search this in Project and see if it is double
> 2. You are importing files in in two classes, like Class A imports Class B and Class B imports Class A. So, if twice import, make one
>      @class, instead of import.

Thanks.

Comment: V S@: I check it also. i'm having single class file in my project.

Comment: Did you check second, import?

Comment: See, where you are importing HomeViewController1, and any of these classes are also imported in HomeViewController1.

Comment: I Check it also, but that  class is not imoprted twice.